# Tomcat Custom LoginModule

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, jaas

I have a web application that accesses an external data source.  The data source has its own access control so I decided to secure my web application by using the external data source as my authentication provider.  To do this I created a custom JAAS LoginModule.  The authentication works great when deployed on Tomcat however upon successful authentication to the external data source, it returns a session key (ex. e2e9c2bf-d1ce-43f4-bc2f-37984c5b28f7) that should be used for subsequent requests for data.

My problem is I'm unable to find a way to store this key in the LoginModule to be used later.  I originally thought creating an HTTP session for the request and storing it as an attribute would work but that doesn't seem possible in LoginModule running on Tomcat. Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.